# How do I easily re-clone a multi-module GIT project under Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I have been successfully using Eclipse with GIT on multi-module projects. To create these projects, I typically use "File->Import->Existing Maven Project" pointing to my local GIT repository.

However, recently I encountered a problem I hadn't thought about. I was having problems with my GIT repository (don't recall the exact details). I was told by our GIT support team that I should simply delete my GIT repository and re-clone it.

However, after I re-cloned it, I discovered that the multi-module project that I had created with this repository under Eclipse was no longer usable. By re-cloning the repository, I managed to delete all the .settings folders and .project files that Eclipse had created in all my module folders. I had to completely delete the Eclipse projects and start over from scratch. I lost a lot of project specific settings.

In retrospect, I wondered what I should have done differently. I thought about copying and saving all the .settings and .project files/folders. Then restore them after I re-clone the repository. However, there were about 20 of each of those files distributed over many folders. So that would be a tedious and error prone task.

Is there a better way to handle this? Is there a way to tell Eclipse to put these files/folders somewhere **outside** the GIT repository? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above solves part of the problem and it helped me discover the full answer. To "re-clone" in place is not directly supported by GIT. However, it is fairly easy to accomplish (This assumes that your working directory is clean and there is nothing to commit).

```
> rm -rf <project name>/.git
```

The next step must be done because GIT does not allow you to clone into an existing project folder. However, you do not want to  create a "bare" repository either as it doesn't create all the indexes in the same way as a regular repository does.

```
> git clone <repo url>/<project name>.git <temp project name>
```

You may want to specify the branch you were on in the original project folder to minimize the unsynchronized cruft in the steps below. Now you can move the .git folder into the original project folder...

```
> mv <temp project name>/.git <project name>
> cd <project name>
```

The next step is optional. It is likely that there will be at least some unstaged and untracked files after this is done. This just lets you know what they are so you do the next steps knowningly.

```
> git status
```

The next steps clean up the unsynchronized files.

```
> git reset --hard
> git clean -fd
```

And finally clean up the temporary project folder.

```
> rm -rf ../<temp project name>
```

I have tried this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the repository (.git/ folder) but not the workspace folder (this does not heal all problems but most). You can also add the files to git - this might be the best idea for stuff which can not be recreated. In my case most of my projects which do not have Eclipse specific files checked in perfectly materialize from the Git on Maven-import.

Comment: So to be clear, are you recommending:  
* > rm -rf <project name>/.git  
* > git clone <repo url>/<project name>.git  ?  
I am reluctant to add these files to GIT as I have not seen a conclusive statement of the wisdom of doing this.

Comment: Yes, or actually making a complete new clone. Then you can use diff against the old work directory.(If you have some time to waste and want to learn of new Git error messages you could also try to heal it in place. From my experience this is easier with "git status" / "git reset" on the command line than with Eclipse EGit gui.)